# Integral of $\int_{1}^{x} \frac{1}{t^2+4}dt$.

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, substitution

I am computing

> $$\int_{1}^{x} \frac{1}{t^2+4}dt$$

I have firstly re-written the problem as:
$$\frac{1}{4} \int_{1}^{x} \frac{1}{(\frac{t^2}{4}+1)}dt,$$
then by substitution of $u=\frac{t}{2},$ this simplifies to:
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{x}{2}} \frac{1}{(u^2+1)}$$
After this step, I was going to use substitution of say p=tan(u), and use trigonometry to simplify. However I have found the following online:
$$\int \frac{u'(t)}{(1+(u(t))^2}dt=arctan(u).$$
I was wondering where this identity came from, so I could use/explain it in my answer, to save having to do the trigonometry.

Thanks :)

Comment: You don't need that identity. It is a standard result that $\int (1+x^2)^{-1}\mathrm{d}x=\arctan x+C$. This is because one can compute the derivative of $\arctan$ directly.

Answer (score 0):

It is a consequence of that fact the$$(\forall x\in\mathbb{R}):\arctan'(x)=\frac1{1+x^2}$$and of the chain rule.

Answer (score 0):

write $$4\left(\frac{t^2}{4}+1\right)=4\left(\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)^2+1\right)$$
and substitute $$u=\frac{t}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Let $t=2\tan u$, giving $dt=2(\tan^2u+1)\,du$.

Then

$$\int\frac{dt}{t^2+4}=\int\frac{2\tan^2u+2}{4\tan^2u+4}du=\frac u2.$$

Answer (score 0):

Recall that if $g(x)$ is the inverse of $f(x)$, then $$\frac{dg}{dx} = \frac{1}{\frac{df}{dx}}$$

So since $y = \arctan x$ and $\tan y = x$, we have

\begin{align*}
\frac{dy}{dx} &= \frac{1}{\frac{d}{dy}\tan y} \\
&= \frac 1{\sec^2 y} \\
&= \frac 1{1 + \tan^2 y} \\
&= \frac 1{1 + x^2}
\end{align*}

So if $$\frac d{du} \arctan u = \frac {u'}{1 + u^2} \tag{Remember the chain rule!}$$ then
$$\int \frac d{du} \arctan u = \int \frac {u'}{1 + u^2}$$ i.e. $$\arctan u = \int \frac {u'}{1 + u^2}$$